# Oracle 11g configuration

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, oracle-11g

I am very new to Oracle 11g installation and configuration, and I am doing this as a part of a POC for a project (that's why not using a latest version). I have installed Oracle database and not sure the next step. These are the details I provided (actually by default) while installation:

```
Global Database Name: orcl.31.91.55
SID: orcl
```

Given below is a screenshot I got immediately after this installation:

[image]

I did the first step (ORACLE_UNQNAME = orcl.31.91.55) and second step throws me this message:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\emctl.bat start dbconsole
OC4J Configuration issue. 
C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1/oc4j/j2ee/OC4J_DBConsole_172.31.91.55_orcl.31.91.55 not found.
```

When I login to web console dashboard, it throws me error:

```
Internal Error has occurred. Check the log file for details.
```

Can someone please help me at the earliest as I am stuck on what to do next for creating a database.

Comment: You know this is only for the Enterprise Manager console and probably no problem for your database itself? Do you need EM?

Comment: @Lenniey, I don't think so. In that case, what is the next step for me? Maybe for creating a database. The intention is to migrate a database from source to this machine.

Comment: Install the database Software. It seems that you just installed EM. And do yourself a favour: consider upgrading your database!